# additional information through a simple_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, haml, simple-form-for

I have:

```
    = simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :post}) do |f|
      = f.error_notification
      .input-row
        = f.input :email, :required => false, :autofocus => true, placeholder: "Enter your email address", :
      .submit-row
        .row
          .col-xs-2
            .cancel
              - if resource_name == :admin
                = link_to "Cancel", new_admin_session_path
              - else
                = link_to "Cancel", new_client_session_path
          .col-xs-10
            = f.submit "Reset Password", :class => "btn btn-primary"
```

I also have `params[:type]` I want to pass that to the next page, which is a generated email that lives in app/views/accounts_mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.haml (I'm not sure how anything knows that that's where it goes)

The question is: How do I get the additional information there, and how to I access it there?

Comment: If it's ok to show it you can add it as a hidden field in the form so it's passed along with all of the other paramets in the form. Then you'd access it in the params hash in the corresponding controller. If you need to access it somewhere else and it's user specific you can always add it to the session hash.

Comment: How do I do those things?

Comment: I'll make an answer up covering it.

Answer (score 0):

Since your form is using the resource helper and I don't know what object it's acting on I'm going to assume it's for a User object. If not you can always adjust accordingly.

In your `/user.rb` model file at the top add (remember to use whichever object your form is acting on):

```
attr_accessor :something
```

In your controller serving the view with your form you should do:

```
@something = params[:type]
```

Then in your `simple_form_for`you can add:

```
= f.hidden_field :something, :value => @something
```

This will pass it to the controller processing your form at which point you would access it as: `params[:user][:something]`

Now if this info needs to never be seen by users and remain in the backend you would skip adding `attr_accessor`, skip defining `@something` in your controller, and skip adding the `hidden_field` in your form and instead do:
`session[:something] = params[:type]` in your controller that renders the form. Then you can access it in any controller afterward just remember users that haven't hit this form will not have it defined.

Comment: I only have access to the information in the view, I think. There doesn't appear to be a controller for this view. I'm using devise, so I think that that's all hidden magic...

Comment: Checkout their docs on generating the devise controllers for customization.  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/#configuring-controllers     In the future I'd recommend skipping devise as it becomes a pain once you start straying off the beaten path. I'm a big fan of using has_secure_password for authentication and building from there.